# Multiple Select-Object as dot-notation

Tags: powershell

**Problem**

I want to know if there is a easy way to search multiple objects in a WMI object or CIM instance.

I'm aware it's possible with commands like

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_BaseBoard | Select-Object Manufacturer,Product
```

But I want a command with a dot notation where you can set multiple objects for a search like `(Get-CimInstance Win32_BaseBoard).Manufacturer` with more than one object.

Something like `(Get-CimInstance Win32_BaseBoard).Object1.Obejct2.Object3`

Comment: Dot notation doesn't work like that. You could do something like this though: `'Manufacturer','Product' | % { (Get-CimInstance Win32_BaseBoard).$_ }`

Comment: Thank you BenH! this will be enough to solve my problem. If someone knows another solution feel free to share it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben's solution from the comments will work but note that it calls `Get-CimInstance` once for each property you want, even though that's unnecessary (could take a while depending on the call you're making).

Let's look at it a few other ways. We'll start by storing the wanted property names in an array.

```
$properties = 'Manufacturer', 'Product'
```

Now we can do something similar to what Ben did:

```
$allValues = $properties |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {
        $bb = Get-CimInstance Win32_Baseboard
    } -Process {
        $bb.$_
    }
```

That keeps his approach but does the CIM call once.

If you want to do with dot notation purely, you can use the `.ForEach()` method and the `.PSObject` hidden property to get at the properties:

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32Baseboard).ForEach({$_.PSObject.Properties.Where({$_.Name -in $properties}).Value})
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted, DotNotation (Intellisense) is 1:1 / single node / collection thing. You can validate this, by pushing the result of the call to XML and walking the nodes.

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32_BaseBoard | ConvertTo-Xml).Objects.Object.Property
(Get-CimInstance Win32_BaseBoard | ConvertTo-Xml).Objects.Object.Property.name
(Get-CimInstance Win32_BaseBoard | ConvertTo-Xml).Objects.Object.Property.'#text'
```

The only other option off the top of my head is constructing a proxy that uses enums and switches for all possible properties for the namespace you are using.

That's way more unneeded effort and code to just do what BenH has pointed out, specifically because you'd have to do that for every class.

Now, if you just wanted to shorthand this, maybe do this

```
$Base = Get-CimInstance Win32_BaseBoard
$Base.Manufacturer;$base.Model;$base.Name;$Base.PartNumber
```

But that is just unwieldy, especially, since all this really doing is single commands set on a single line with the command break separator, the semi-colon. Which is a wrong thing to do. IMHO.

---small rant ---
If you need the separator, then just put the next thing on a new line and avoid the semi-colon. I mean, I can see that semi-colon use as the PoSH console host, but in a real script, function, module, well, just, no. Again, IMHO
--- small rant ---

Lastly, depending on what your target PoSH version is, DotNotation had issues in v2 - v3 days

Comment: What issues did dot notation have in v2/v3?

Comment: I had issues, with it when using DN on v3 but send the code to v2 systems. Similar oddities had been reported by several other folks to date. See: 'community.spiceworks.com/topic/581356-can-someone-explain-ps-dot-notation'
See Martin9700's comment.

Comment: That's not an issue so much as is it is a well-known feature change that happened from v2 to v3, which is exactly what Martin9700's comment (and most after it) describe. Expecting to use language features introduced in v3, in v2, isn't really a reasonable expectation. There are have been no further syntax changes since then, and in both v2 and v3+, the syntax works as described / intended.